# Compiling but crashing android app. something to do with intent? help

Tags: java, android, twitter, mobile

It keeps crashing. I think it has something to do with the Intent. Please help.

```
    package com.SMARTlab.twitterapp;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import twitter4j.*;

    public class TwitterApp extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
            search.setOnClickListener(search_OnClickListener);
        }
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.search_button:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, com.SMARTlab.twitterapp.TwitterApp.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private Button.OnClickListener search_OnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            int queryRank = 0;
            private boolean evaluateRank(int rank)
            {
                if (rank > 10)
                return true;
                return false;
            }
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Twitter t = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_box);
                TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_box);
                Query q = new Query(ed.getText().toString());
                QueryResult res = null;
                try
                {
                    res = t.search(q);
                    txt.setText("");

                }
                catch(TwitterException ex) {System.out.println(ex.toString());}
                for (Tweet tw : res.getTweets())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        long[] id = t.getRetweetedByIDs(tw.getId()).getIDs();
                        for (int x = 0; x < id.length; x++)
                            queryRank += 1;
                    } catch(TwitterException te) {}
                    if (evaluateRank(queryRank))
                    {
                        txt.append((String)"[" + tw.getFromUser() + "] " + tw.getText() + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Here is the LogCat.

```
06-10 12:44:08.145: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(416): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-10 12:44:08.145: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(416): CheckJNI is ON
06-10 12:44:08.365: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(416): --- registering native functions ---
06-10 12:44:09.285: DEBUG/dalvikvm(253): GC_EXPLICIT freed 176 objects / 8856 bytes in 55ms
06-10 12:44:10.446: DEBUG/PackageParser(59): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl44188.tmp
06-10 12:44:10.647: INFO/PackageManager(59): Removing non-system package:com.SMARTlab.twitter
06-10 12:44:10.647: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.SMARTlab.twitter uid=10039
06-10 12:44:11.455: DEBUG/PackageManager(59): Scanning package com.SMARTlab.twitter
06-10 12:44:11.465: INFO/PackageManager(59): Package com.SMARTlab.twitter codePath changed from /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-2.apk to /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
06-10 12:44:11.475: INFO/PackageManager(59): /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk changed; unpacking
06-10 12:44:11.556: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk' ---
06-10 12:44:14.765: DEBUG/dalvikvm(423): DexOpt: load 105ms, verify 473ms, opt 23ms
06-10 12:44:16.048: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk' (success) ---
06-10 12:44:16.246: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9625 objects / 558632 bytes in 176ms
06-10 12:44:16.246: WARN/PackageManager(59): Code path for pkg : com.SMARTlab.twitter changing from /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-2.apk to /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk
06-10 12:44:16.246: WARN/PackageManager(59): Resource path for pkg : com.SMARTlab.twitter changing from /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-2.apk to /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk
06-10 12:44:16.246: DEBUG/PackageManager(59):   Activities: com.SMARTlab.twitter.Twitter
06-10 12:44:16.288: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.SMARTlab.twitter uid=10039
06-10 12:44:17.117: INFO/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk@classes.dex
06-10 12:44:17.117: DEBUG/PackageManager(59): New package installed in /data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk
06-10 12:44:17.975: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.SMARTlab.twitter uid=10039
06-10 12:44:18.065: DEBUG/dalvikvm(124): GC_EXPLICIT freed 910 objects / 48976 bytes in 67ms
06-10 12:44:18.166: DEBUG/dalvikvm(151): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1750 objects / 89136 bytes in 89ms
06-10 12:44:18.456: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(59): no available voice recognition services found
06-10 12:44:18.775: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5654 objects / 334424 bytes in 261ms
06-10 12:44:19.115: INFO/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.SMARTlab.twitter-2.apk@classes.dex
06-10 12:44:19.196: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(416): Shutting down VM
06-10 12:44:19.216: DEBUG/dalvikvm(416): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-10 12:44:19.236: INFO/AndroidRuntime(416): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-10 12:44:19.955: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(429): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-10 12:44:19.955: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(429): CheckJNI is ON
06-10 12:44:20.175: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(429): --- registering native functions ---
06-10 12:44:21.025: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.SMARTlab.twitter/.Twitter }
06-10 12:44:21.135: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(429): Shutting down VM
06-10 12:44:21.175: DEBUG/dalvikvm(429): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-10 12:44:21.215: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.SMARTlab.twitter for activity com.SMARTlab.twitter/.Twitter: pid=435 uid=10039 gids={}
06-10 12:44:21.255: INFO/AndroidRuntime(429): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-10 12:44:21.446: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 264 objects / 10144 bytes in 203ms
06-10 12:44:21.656: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 22 objects / 968 bytes in 163ms
06-10 12:44:21.786: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 64 bytes in 115ms
06-10 12:44:22.175: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(435): Shutting down VM
06-10 12:44:22.175: WARN/dalvikvm(435): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.SMARTlab.twitter/com.SMARTlab.twitter.Twitter}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.SMARTlab.twitter.Twitter in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk]
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.SMARTlab.twitter.Twitter in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.SMARTlab.twitter-1.apk]
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
06-10 12:44:22.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(435):     ... 11 more
06-10 12:44:22.205: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.SMARTlab.twitter/.Twitter
06-10 12:44:22.716: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44ff66d0 com.SMARTlab.twitter/.Twitter}
06-10 12:44:25.756: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44eb2308
06-10 12:44:26.025: INFO/Process(435): Sending signal. PID: 435 SIG: 9
06-10 12:44:26.155: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Process com.SMARTlab.twitter (pid 435) has died.
06-10 12:44:28.866: DEBUG/dalvikvm(261): GC_EXPLICIT freed 45 objects / 2120 bytes in 63ms
06-10 12:44:33.570: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44ff66d0 com.SMARTlab.twitter/.Twitter}
06-10 12:45:37.688: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.SMARTlab.twitterapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TwitterApp"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: could you please post the output from logcat so we can see the stack track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `Twitter` is registered in your [AndroidManifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) as an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

On your line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Twitter.class);
startActivity(i);
```

twitter4j.Twitter is an interface, not an activity class. There is no way to launch this as an activity, so it's guaranteed to crash. If you've created an activity named `Twitter`, you will have full qualify one or the other; ex:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, com.SMARTlab.twitter.Twitter.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I posted this as you were posting your manifest... you're importing twitter4j.* (Which includes a Twitter interface), and you have a class in your package named Twitter... there's a conflict. You should avoid naming your classes anything that will even potentially interfere with 3rd party SDKs you are using.

Comment: Also, your activity is named `TwitterApp`, yet your manifest refers to just `Twitter`.

Comment: Updated the code, and the manifest. The app no longer crashes. but I get the error:

[2011-06-10 13:21:14 - TwitterApp] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.SMARTlab.twitterapp/com.SMARTlab.twitterapp.TwitterApp} does not exist.

Comment: The Manifest should be fine with just `.TwitterApp` since the packagename is specified in the manifest tag. The important part was fully qualifying it in code.

Comment: I had that, and it was still crashing. I tried cleaning the code using elipse's built in clean function, and the app no longer crashes. Thats eclipse for ya! Thank you for your help!